# Equilateral pentagon with increasing/equal angles

Tags: geometry

> Suppose all sides of a convex pentagon ABCDE have the same size, and $\angle A \ge \angle B \ge \angle C \ge \angle D \ge \angle E $. Prove that this pentagon is a regular pentagon.

I know this should be proved using contradiction, but I'm not sure how to reach that point. Can anyone guide me to the right solution?

Comment: Calculate the sum of the angles then divide by $5$.  DONE!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Could you please elaborate? I'm not sure how that would help solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOLOG, we only need to consider the case where the side of the equilateral pentagon is $1$ and the vertices $A,B,C,D,E$ are ordered counterclockiwisely
on circumference of the pentagon.

Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon$ be the external angles at $A, B, C, D, E$. We have

$$\angle A \ge \angle B \ge \angle C \ge \angle D \ge \angle E
\quad\implies\quad \alpha \le \beta \le \gamma \le \delta \le \epsilon
$$
Since $2\pi = \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta + \epsilon \le 5 \epsilon$,
we have $\epsilon \ge \frac{2\pi}{5}$. This leads to
$$\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta \le \frac{8\pi}{5}
\implies \alpha + \beta \le \frac{4\pi}{5}
\implies \alpha \le \frac{2\pi}{5}
$$

Choose a coordinate system so that $E = (-\frac12,0), A = (\frac12,0)$.
In this coordinate system, it is not hard to see the $x$-coordinate of $C$ is
$$\frac12 + \cos\alpha + \cos(\alpha+\beta)
\ge \frac12 + \cos\frac{2\pi}{5} + \cos\frac{4\pi}{5} = 0\tag{*1}$$
THis means $C$ is lying in the left-half plane and hence $|AC| \le |EC|$.

However 
$$\begin{align} &|AC|^2 = |AB|^2 + |BC|^2  + 2|AB||BC|\cos\beta = 2(1+\cos\beta)\\
& |CE|^2 = |CD|^2 + |DE|^2 + 2|CD||DE|\cos\delta = 2(1+\cos\delta)
\end{align}
$$
Together with $\beta \le \delta$, we obtain $|AC| \ge |EC|$.

Combine with above, we get $|AC| = |EC|$. This forces $C$ to lies on the $y$-axis.

Notice if either $\alpha < \frac{2\pi}{5}$ or $\alpha + \beta < \frac{4\pi}{5}$, the inequality in $(*1)$ becomes strict. For $C$ to lies on the $y$-axis, we need
$\alpha = \frac{2\pi}{5}$. This leads to

$$2\pi = 5\alpha \le \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta + \epsilon = 2\pi$$
Since $\alpha \le \beta \le \gamma \le \delta \le \epsilon$, this forces
$\alpha = \beta = \gamma = \delta = \epsilon$ and
$ABCDE$ is a regular pentagon.

Comment: Shouldn't (*1) imply that C is on the right side of the plane instead of the left?